# How to increase the population size of genetic algorithm using jenetics.io library in Java?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

```
I am trying to get started using the Jenetics JAVA library for genetic algorithms and there is something I don't understand from my GA limited background.
I need to change the default value of population size which is set to 50 into a different value using populationSize().

here is my code segment
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        initArrays();
        final Factory<Genotype<IntegerGene>> gtf = Genotype.of(IntegerChromosome.of(0, TRUCKS.length - 1, LEN), IntegerChromosome.of(0, LOCATIONS.length - 1, LEN), IntegerChromosome.of(0, TIMES.length - 1, LEN));
        final Engine<IntegerGene, Integer> engine = Engine.builder(Main::eval, gtf)
                .populationSize(int 150)
                .build();
        System.out.println("engine.getPopulationSize() = " + engine.getPopulationSize());
        final EvolutionResult<IntegerGene, Integer> result = engine.stream().limit(1000).collect(EvolutionResult.toBestEvolutionResult());
        Genotype<IntegerGene> genotype = result.getBestPhenotype().getGenotype();
        System.out.println("result = " + genotype);
        System.out.println("result.getBestPhenotype().getFitness() = " + result.getBestPhenotype().getFitness());
    }`enter code here`
```

populationSize() is where I get the error.I need to change the default value of 50 to 150.

Comment: What have you tried have you had any errors or notices?

Comment: In addition, please copy-paste your code into the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Yes I did. I have included my code in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have to remove the `int` keyword from the `populationSize` method call:

```
final Engine<IntegerGene, Integer> engine = Engine.builder(Main::eval, gtf)
    .populationSize(150)
    .build();
```